# Adding a user to my "free Google Apps account" over my allocation of free users

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-for-work

I've got a Google Apps for Business account with 3 domains registered to it.

The account was setup when they were still issuing free accounts with 10 users and I have since used all my 10 user allocations.

I now want to add an 11th user / email address to the account. To do so will I just have to pay for 1 user (e.g., 10 free + 1 paid) or will I have to start paying for all 11?

(Just in case someone asks I need the 11th user to have an email address on one of my domains, so I can't just create a free Google Drive account as they need to use email also.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add the 11th user in your domain, you will have to upgrade to at least G Suite Basic as the max number of users for the Free edition is 10. You cannot purchase additional licenses and stay on the Free version.

Upgrading to G Suite Basic can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?hl=en).